# Ruby on Rails vs KSOAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ksoap

Can somebody quickly brief me on the advantages and disadvantages of ksoap and ruby over rails please? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If KSOAP is http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/, then there is no comparison. One (kSOAP) is a library for web services communication via the SOAP protocol, the other (Rails) is a tool for building web sites. Completely different uses.